# Java: Variable is already defined in method

Tags: java, random

I am trying to make a program which makes a random number between 1000-9999 with no repeating numbers. The rules are I have to label the random number as a String, and then use a while loop to figure out if any of the numbers repeat.

```
//generating random number
double answer1 = (Math.random() * 9000)+1000;

//converting answer
int answer2 = (int)answer1;
String answer = answer2 + " ";

//Labeling arrays
answer.toCharArray();

//**NEW** checking random number
while (answer.charAt(0) == answer.charAt(0)
       || answer.charAt(0) == answer.charAt(1)
       || answer.charAt(0) == answer.charAt(2)
       || answer.charAt(0) == answer.charAt(3)
       || answer.charAt(1) == answer.charAt(1)
       || answer.charAt(1) == answer.charAt(2)
       || answer.charAt(1) == answer.charAt(3)
       || answer.charAt(2) == answer.charAt(2)
       || answer.charAt(2) == answer.charAt(3)
       || answer.charAt(3) == answer.charAt(3)); //you have my apologies
{
    ////generating random number
    double answer1 = (Math.random() * 9000)+1000;

    //converting answer
    int answer2 = (int)answer1;
    String answer = answer2 + "
}
```

I know the while parameters are extremely long, but it was necessary to make sure none of the numbers repeated. I assumed that I could regenerate a new random number and test it again in the while loop, but I get the error that variables answer1, answer, and answer2 are already defined in my main method. Does anyone have a tip as to what I can do to generate a new random number until none of the numbers repeat?

Comment: Did you read the stack trace? It tells you which line has the problem.

Comment: How is a condition that starts with `answer.charAt(0) == answer.charAt(0)` ever going to be false?

Answer (score 6):

You've already define your variable `answer2` in `line 2`,  and in your while loop you are trying to redefine the variable `answer2`, i.e:

```
int answer2 = (int)answer1;
```

You can do it like :

```
answer2 = (int)answer1;
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is the main issue (you may have more than one), but a ; should not terminate a while statement. It should be `while (..) { }`, not `while (..); { }`.

As for your error about redefinition, you cannot define the variable again that was already defined in a larger scope. For this instance, line 2, `int answer2 = (int) answer1` already defined answer2. In the while loop, you just have to use the variable again and you do not need to define it. So it should be:

```
  while (...)
  {
     ////generating random number
     answer1 = (Math.random() * 9000)+1000;

     //converting answer
     answer2 = (int)answer1;
     answer = answer2 + " ";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is so much wrong with this question that it boggles the mind.

However specifically: you are redefining variables in the same scope which is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

```
 answer.toCharArray(); // here you use answer variable
```

and than your loop closed

```
while(conditon);
```

than again you define answer variable inside {  }

```
String answer = answer2 + " "; // duplicate
```

---

you should use if for the condition and terminate the ; from while like

```
while(condition){
 }
```

and use

```
 answer = answer2 + " ";
```

instead of

```
 String answer = answer2 + " ";
```