# Compilation Error at Enhanced For-Loop. i is already defined in main method but I need integer i for the for loop

Tags: java, arrays

Hello StackOverflow Community.

I was working on a Java program using Arrays and 12 integer inputs to then find evens, odds, and negatives and separate them into 3 different arrays.

The program looks as though it should compile and run as intended but it gives me an error at the enhanced for loop saying that `variable i is already defined in method main(java.lang.String[])`

I already looked at this post and it did not help me with my for-loop issue.
[Java: Variable is already defined in method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23148347/java-variable-is-already-defined-in-method)

Here is the program:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      
int [] twelveInt = new int [12];
      
int countEven = 0;
      
int countOdd = 0;
      
int countNeg = 0;
      
int i = 0;
      
for (i = 0; i < twelveInt.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter the #" + (i + 1) + " integer.");
    twelveInt [i] = in.nextInt();
  
    if (twelveInt[i] % 2 == 0){
        countEven++;
    }
    if (twelveInt[i] % 2 != 0){
        countOdd++;
    }
    if (twelveInt[i] < 0){
        countNeg++;
    }          
}

    
int [] evens = new int [countEven];    
int [] odds = new int [countOdd];
int [] negatives = new int [countNeg];
    

countEven = 0;
countOdd = 0;
countNeg = 0;
    

for (int i : twelveInt) {
        if (i % 2 == 0){
            evens[countEven++] = i;
        }
        if (i % 2 != 0){
            odds[countOdd++] = i;
        }
        if (i < 0){
            negatives[countNeg++] = i;
        }          
    }
          
System.out.println("Here are the Even numbers you entered");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(evens));
      
System.out.println("Here are the Odd numbers you entered");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(odds));
      
System.out.println("Here are the Negative numbers you entered");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(negatives));
```

Any help with this strange bug is greatly appreciated.

Comment: this question was reposted?

Comment: @Syncit When I do this, I get an Outof Bounds error for the Evens counter.

Comment: I have answered this question previously. But the user deleted and reraise as another question. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int i = 0;
      
for (i = 0; i < twelveInt.length; i++) {
```

Change it to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < twelveInt.length; i++) {
```